# How to fix 401 Unauthorized response WP Rest API

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

Im making a request to another wordpress site on our network as below.

```
    //Send the request to update the submission post
    $response = wp_remote_request( $this->urls->assign_url, array(
            'headers'     => array(
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                'Authentication' => 'Basic '.base64_encode('somename:somepassword')
            ),
            'body'        => json_encode($array),
            'method'      => 'POST',
            'data_format' => 'body'
        )
    );
```

- Im making this request via ajax.
- The callback function is being called and sends back data.
- Im also logged into the remote site.
- Im using a nonce and the user being authorised in the headers is a valid user.

All I keep getting back is:

```
body: "{"code":"rest_not_logged_in","message":"You are not currently logged in.","data":{"status":401}}"
```

Ive only just started getting this since I updated the remote wordpress version. It was working fine before that.

Any thoughts.

Comment: Are you using default authentication or a plug-in?  I don't see the nonce in your request but may be misunderstanding.

Comment: Nonce is passed in the js to the callback function and checked before the this http request. Im not using a plugin, this is just default user auth. The user is a simple admin user on the remote site.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in order to authenticate the way you want to, you need to use a plugin - the built-in authentication method is not ideal for offsite requests since it is cookie based.

https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/#authentication-plugins